# Woman and Zimun: What is the requirement?

Tags: halacha, women, bentching, meal-seudah, zimun

What is a woman's requirement to say Bircat Hamazon with a Zimun of **women**?

What is a woman's requirement to say Bircat Hamazon with a Zimun of **men**?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in Orach Chaim Siman 199 Paragraph 7 says:

שולחן ערוך אורח חיים סימן קצט:ז
נשים מזמנות לעצמן - רשות. אבל כשאוכלות עם האנשים, חייבות ויוצאות בזמון שלנו.

Women can do a Zimun alone.  It is a רשות (optional).  But if they are with three men, then the women are obligated (with the men), and a man would lead.

The Beiur Halacha quoted below states that according to the GR”A even a group of women eating without men have a חוב (obligation) to create a Zimun.  However, he notes this is not how the world is accustomed.

ביאור הלכה סימן קצט ד"ה נשים מזמנות
ודעת הגר"א בביאורו שהעיקר כהרא"ש ותר"י שנשים מזמנות לעצמן חוב. אך העולם לא נהגו כן

Comment: According to the Shulchan Aruch HaRav, the women who ate with men may split off if they want and would remain **obligated** to perform their own zimmun.

Comment: @DoubleAA What if just one woman splits off? May she?

Comment: @sah I'm not sure I understand the case. If 3 men eat with one woman, she is obligated in Zimmun just like the men and all of them must bentch together.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm just wondering, what if the women who split off are less than the number who would be obligated in a women's zimun. Could/should they make a zimun with two? Or in that case would they be obliged to stay with the men?

Comment: @sah men or women can only split off from a group in groups sufficient that they can perform the same level Zimmun. So if there is no minyan groups can split off such that each group has three and if there is a minyan they can split such that each group has a minyan.

Comment: Does Reshut here mean Mitzva but not Chovah?

Comment: @DoubleAA Good question.  Presumably there is a קיום in giving the enhanced שבח of the ברכה.

Comment: @DoubleAA This actually happened to me - we were at a family Shabbos meal with 3 men and >3 women.  Someone got a terrible headache in the middle of the meal and had to lie down and so we lost our male zimun.  I said that as I understood it the women are still required to do zimun (and they did).

Comment: @Heshy אשריך ואשרן

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure how seriously to take this diyuk, but the MB 199:12 seems to imply that we should have done a zimun of the 2 remaining men + the women. Since it was a family meal we were in the category of אין נכון rather than אין רשאין, and I can imagine that a preexisting chiyuv would override an אין נכון.