# Formulation of Women's Zimmun

Tags: women, bentching, zimun

According to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3874/1713), three women who have eaten together may make a zimmun. The usual formulation of the zimmun, "רבותי נברך", does not make sense for women. What formulation should women use when making a zimmun?

Comment: What's wrong with rabbotai?

Comment: I thought the formulation of zimmun was נברך שאכלנו משלו.

Comment: How about הב לן ונברך (P'sachim 103b, cf. Chullin 86b).

Comment: ...or "Señoras [bendigamos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendigamos)", for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan's answer addresses the salutation.

The invitation to bless, however, might also do well to be adjusted.  While in modern Hebrew (and, indeed, for a very long time, historically) the feminine, plural, first person call to bless is the same as the masculine (נברך), a more archaic form of the word (and thus, perhaps, a more correspondingly appropriate feminine equivalent to the standard men's Zimmun) is נברכנה.

I would suggest that an appropriate formulation (though by no means the only valid formulation) would be גברותי נברכנה.

That's assuming you stick with Hebrew, of course.

Comment: What about נברכנה שאכלנו משלו?

Comment: @DoubleAA, that would be valid. I think the question, perhaps unnecessarily, is trying to stick with the "standard" formulation for the introductory line and call to bless, and just looking for a tweak. But feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: (@DoubleAA forgive me if I assumed incorrectly that you mean to dispense with "רבותי נברך", as in your comment on the question.)

Comment: I don't mean to dispense with it or not, just to ask (the only interesting question available which is) about the only halachicly meaningful line in the Zimmun. Can/should/does it get adjusted for gender?

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Dr. Ari Zivotofsky, in his article on women's zimmun (published in the OU's *Jewish Action* Magazine, Fall 5760/1999 issue ([link](http://www.ou.org/torah/article/tzarich_iyun_womens_zimun))), suggests gevirotai or chaverotai.